# Get div with class with Goutte

Tags: php, goutte

I'm trying to get data from this [url](http://sp.cadastrosindustriais.com.br/?consulta=cal%C3%A7ados) with [Goutte](https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/Goutte)
But when I try to filter only the divs with class  "empresa", I get the entire page.
How can I filter only the divs with a specific class?

This is my code:

```
<html>

<body>
        <?php

        require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
        use Goutte\Client;

        $client = new Client();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://sp.cadastrosindustriais.com.br/?consulta=cal%C3%A7ados');

        $crawler->filter('div[id="empresa"]')->each(function ($node) {
            print $node->text()."\n";
        });


        ?>

</body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're close. The problem is your selector. The [crawler](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/dom_crawler.html) uses [jquery style selectors](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

Here's a working example of your code. I put the results inside an array just in case you wanted to do more than just dump the results.

```
$client = new Goutte\Client();
$crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://sp.cadastrosindustriais.com.br/?consulta=cal%C3%A7ados');
    
$elements = $crawler->filter('.empresa')->each(function($node){
    return $node->text();
});
```

Then if you want to traverse through the results, you can just do `foreach($elements as $e)`